# Heroku Still Displays Default Rails Home Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've removed `index.html` from the public server, and mapped a different controller's action to be the root. This works fine locally.

I've pushed the app to Heroku, but it still displays the old index.html file. Funny thing is, when I `ls` in the `public` folder on my Heroku app, `index.html` is missing, like it should be.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is probably too obvious, but did you clear the cache in your browser and reload?

Comment: Et voilà! Too easy. I feel ashamed of myself. Thanks!

Comment: No worries---happens to the best of us. :) I'll repost my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try clearing the cache in your browser and reloading? The `index.html` file may still be in cache there.